# How to optimize this Nhibernate Query (835ms)

Tags: nhibernate, optimization, linq-to-nhibernate, activerecordlinq

I have this query

```
var temp = from x in ActiveRecordLinq.AsQueryable<Circuits>()
                       where x.User_Created == false
                       orderby x.Description
                       select x;
```

From NHibernate Profiler
Query duration
 -Database only: 7ms
 -Total: 835ms

The query generated:

```
SELECT   this_.Circuit_ID     as Circuit1_35_0_,
     this_.[Description]  as column2_35_0_,
         this_.[User_Created] as column3_35_0_
FROM     dbo.Circuit this_
WHERE    this_.[User_Created] = 0 /* @p0 */
ORDER BY this_.[Description] asc
```

It seems like a pretty straightforward query. It returns 6821 rows. All I'm using this for is to populate a dropdownlist.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's nothing you can optimize there. Retrieving almost 7k rows and displaying them in a dropdown is just bad design.

Comment: The only thing you can optimize is the number of items in that dropdown :) . Can you do something like an autocomplete ?

Comment: @Diego, I'm just updating the current design (switching from sql). The user needs to be able to select a circuit and there just happens to be 7k of them now. How would you go abouts implementing this?

Comment: @sirrocco, What do you mean like autocomplete? Partial loading of the list?

Comment: Show a textbox to the user with nothing loaded, let them type .. 3-4 letters and then filter the your table based on those .. it should limit the number of items to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, if you insist on the 7k (I *REALLY* believe you should stop to rethink your design... but...), you could try doing an HQL query to just select the fields you need from the object, instead of querying for the objects themselves.

With the query you have written, nHibernate is loading the data from the database which occurs pretty quickly as you have noted. But THEN based on the Linq query you have written it is initializing, populating and returning 7k Circuit objects. which is probably taking it a while...

And since you aren't actually using the "object" in any meaningful way in this case (just a text and value pair for the dropdown) you really don't need nHibernate to build the objects.

Try changing your code to just return the text/value pair with HQL or LinqToNHibernate.

the HQL would look something like this:

```
select c.description, c.id from Circuit c
where c.ordercreated = false
orderby c.description
```

I know you can do this with LinqToNhibernate as well, I just don't have any quick examples at hand.

Comment: That's what i ended up trying. When I selected x.Description instead of just x it cut the time in half. Since this is only happening on startup I am going to leave it in since once the user opens the program they tend to leave it open

Answer (score 1):

Wait... you are putting nearly 7k items in a dropdown list? Am I understanding that correctly?

If so, would it be possible to use dependent dropdown lists with ajax or some similar design?

If this is on the web, you are likely looking at a relatively large page that needs to be transmitted down to a client computer, so optimizing the NH query may be a premature optimization...

Comment: Yes 7k items to a dropdown list lol. Its a C# application running from a network share.

Answer (score 1):

7k entries on a dropdown list is bad for the user experience. Since you are already ordering by Description i assume the your users already know (at least partially) what they want to select. So giving a full list is actually hindering the user.

Since you are asking what an autocompleter is

imagine an input field where the user types a number of characters. When the user types what he wants, then the query will fire. This string parameter will be used to further limit down the size of the result set.

so your query implementation is something like this pseudocode:

```
//passedParameter => "%foo%"
var temp = from x in ActiveRecordLinq.AsQueryable<Circuits>()
              where x.User_Created == false
                and x.Description like passedParameter
              orderby x.Description
              select x;
```

The actual implementation on both the query as well as if you decide to implement '%foo%' or 'foo%' etc it's your decision.

The user experience will be reduced to writing 'foo' in the input field and the results will only fetch the relevant `Circuits` on which the user will select what he wants. If the result set is still too large the user can add 'b' to the already typed 'foo' making a 'foob' where again the query fires again returning an even more limited result set.

When you type at google and it gives you suggestions on the fly its an autocompleter implementation

Comment: That's what I figured, the only problem with that is that the user needs to be able to type in there own Circuit name as well(One of the reasons the list is so large). Yes I would have designed it differently but it's way past that point.